# c# Delete row from DataTable and use TableAdapter.Update and .Fill

Tags: c#, database, datatable, tableadapter

Why is the DataTable not empty even after it has been cleared?

In the beginning I cleared the the "PasswoerterDataTable". But afte updating and filling it back it is not empty anymore. Did I misunderstood the usage of the .fill and .update commands? How do I correct my mistake so that the **"PasswoerterDataTable" is empty** in the end?

```
PasswoerterDataTable.Rows.Clear();
// DataTable is now empty
PasswoerterTableAdapter.Update(PasswoerterDataTable);
PasswoerterTableAdapter.Fill(PasswoerterDataTable);
// DataTable is not empty anymore. Why?
```

I know that it does not make sense to use .update and .fill after each other but I am currently  working on a PasswordManager and I want to delete Passwords. These deleted Passwords should not appaer when the program is closed and started again but I need to use .fill after Startup to get the Passwords which haven't been deleted. But after I used .fill the Passwords reappear.

Comment: The work of the fill method is to load the data from the database table and _fill_ the in memory DataTable object. So there is nothing out of order in finding your in memory DataTable filled with data after a call to Fill

Comment: Do you expect that the Clear method followed by the Update method deletes the rows in the database table? No, it doesn't work in that way. Clear removes the rows from the in memory DataTable so, the Update method doesn't find anything to Update. If you want to delete the rows with the Update method then you should call Delete on each row of your _PasswoerterDataTable_

Comment: @Steve Yes you are right I expected that the clear method followed by the update method clears the rows in the database Table. Thank you very much for your quick reply Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Fill* method exists to read data from a database table and put it inside an in memory DataTable object. I think you are misunderstanding the work of the *Clear* method and the *Update* method.

The *Clear* method removes all rows from the in memory datatable but doesn't change anything on the database table. The Update method looks at the rows present in your *PasswoerterDataTable* and checks their [RowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) property. If it finds [something to update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) then a command is executed to reflect the changes back to the database.
But you have cleared the rows from *PasswoerterDataTable* so Update has nothing to update and your database table is left unchanged. The following Fill reloads everything.

If you want Update to execute delete commands on the database you need to set the *RowState* of each row to *Deleted*. And you can do this with

```
foreach(DataRow row in PasswoerterDataTable.Rows)
    row.Delete();  // This doesn't remove the row, but sets its RowState to Deleted

// Now the adapter knows what to do...
PasswoerterTableAdapter.Update();
```

Of course this is totally unnecessary and you can simply write a single Command to act directly on your database to TRUNCATE your table

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE PasswoerterTable", connection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
PasswoerterDataTable.Rows.Clear(); 
// No need to call Fill again.
```